# while selecting the data from tables im getting the error

Tags: sql-server

SQL :

```
select E.ID
    , cp = (
        select ISNULL(C.CNAME, E.CP) CP
        from TBL_EXPEDITE_MASTER E
        left join [NEPTUNE122].BB_PROVISION.DBO.BI_CUSTOMERS C on C.spid = E.CP
        )
    , E.ECO_ORDER
    , E.DN
    , E.CBUK
    , E.XMPF_ID
    , E.CP
    , E.RECEIVED
    , E.CP_OWNER
    , E.CP_CONTACT_NUMBER
    , CP_EMAIL
    , E.CPREF
    , E.SITE_CONTACT_NAME
    , E.SITE_CONTACT_NUMBER
    , E.EXISTING_CRD
    , E.NEW_CRD
    , E.EXPEDITE_CRD
    , E.status
    , E.LINE
    , E.CHARGEABLE
    , E.RESPONSE
    , LAST_UPDATED
    , ORDER_TYPE
    , INITIALRESP
    , NOTES
    , BTW_EXPEDITE_REF --1.2
    , ProductType --1.2
    , InstallationAddress --1.2
    , SITE_CONTACT_OTHER --1.2
    , FastTrackReason --1.2
    , FastTrackFOC --1.2
    , FOC_Reason --1.2
    , CP_EMAIL_OTHER --1.2
    , Received_Via --1.2
    , E2EData --1.2
    , E.organisationName
    , E.postCode
    , E.thoroughfareDescriptor
    , E.county
    , E.country
from TBL_EXPEDITE_MASTER E with (nolock)
```

Error Message

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g88F.jpg):

Comment: Error is quite clear, what don't you understand about it?

Comment: We need more information. As @JayasuryaSatheesh mentioned, the error is thrown by the subquery as it returns more than 1 row. Now, there are a couple of options here, like the ones Jayasurya Satheesh mentioned in his answer, but we need to clarify two scenarios.
1) If we leave the subquery in the SELECT part we need a `TOP 1` operator in combination with an `ORDER BY`, applied on a column with unique values.
2) If we move the subquery to the JOIN section in the top-level select we need to know what should be done with duplicate rows. Filter? Keep? Return only distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because in the First Select the SubQuery you are using has returned more than 1 Record for the same row.

You May try using top 1 to avoid this error or any aggregate functions or Join the subquery as a separate CTE will also work fine.

For a Quick Fix, you can change the query like this

```
SELECT cp =
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(C.CNAME, E.CP) CP
    FROM TBL_EXPEDITE_MASTER E
         LEFT JOIN [NEPTUNE122].BB_PROVISION.DBO.BI_CUSTOMERS C ON C.spid = E.CP 
ORDER BY C.CNAME, E.CP
);
```

but looking at your query, I think this will also work

```
SELECT 
    E.ID,
    cp = ISNULL(C.CNAME, E.CP),
    E.ECO_ORDER,
    E.DN,
    E.CBUK,
    E.XMPF_ID,
    E.CP,
    E.RECEIVED,
    E.CP_OWNER,
    E.CP_CONTACT_NUMBER,
    CP_EMAIL,
    E.CPREF,
    E.SITE_CONTACT_NAME,
    E.SITE_CONTACT_NUMBER,
    E.EXISTING_CRD,
    E.NEW_CRD,
    E.EXPEDITE_CRD,
    E.STATUS,
    E.LINE,
    E.CHARGEABLE,
    E.RESPONSE,
    LAST_UPDATED,
    ORDER_TYPE,
    INITIALRESP,
    NOTES,
    BTW_EXPEDITE_REF,
    ProductType,
    InstallationAddress,
    SITE_CONTACT_OTHER,
    FastTrackReason,
    FastTrackFOC,
    FOC_Reason,
    CP_EMAIL_OTHER,
    Received_Via,
    E2EData,
    E.organisationName,
    E.postCode,
    E.thoroughfareDescriptor,
    E.county,
    E.country
    FROM TBL_EXPEDITE_MASTER E WITH (NOLOCK)
       LEFT JOIN [NEPTUNE122].BB_PROVISION.DBO.BI_CUSTOMERS C 
          ON C.spid = E.CP
```

Comment: `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` is not accurate and could return inconsistent results over time.

Comment: I've added order by Clause @RaduGheorghiu

Comment: (**after edit**) : what about duplicate rows, since you're left join-ing?

Comment: That's a point, but can't tell exactly about it without knowing the sample input and expected output